# Current status of colClasses argument in function ff:read.csv.ffdf (ff - R package)

Tags: r, ff, read.csv

Error `vmode 'character' not implemented` occours due to argument `colClasses=c("id"="character")` in below code :

```
df <- read.csv.ffdf('TenGBsample.csv',
      colClasses=c("id"="character"), VERBOSE=TRUE)
```

> read.table.ffdf 1..1000 (1000)  csv-read=0.02secError in ff(initdata =
>   initdata, length = length, levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  :
>   vmode 'character' not implemented

where first column in `TenGBsample.csv` is 'id' and consist of 30 digit numbers, which exceeds maximum number on my 64-bit system (Windows), I would like to handle them as character, second column contain small numbers, so there is no need for adjustment.

I've checked, and there is 'character' mode for `vmode` : http://127.0.0.1:16624/library/ff/html/vmode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following from `help(read.csv.ffdf)`

> ... `read.table.ffdf` has been designed to behave as much 
>   like `read.table` as possible. However, note the following differences:
>
> 3. **character vectors are not supported**, character data must be
>      read as one of the following colClasses: 'Date', 'POSIXct', 'factor, 'ordered'. By default character columns are read as factors.
>      Accordingly arguments 'as.is' and 'stringsAsFactors' are not allowed.

So you cannot read the value in as character.  But if you already have numeric values for the `id` column in the file, then you could read them in as doubles and re-format them afterward.  `format(x, scientific = FALSE)` will print `x` in standard notation.

Here's an example data set `x` where `id` is numeric and has 30 digits.

```
library(ff)

x <- data.frame(
    id = (267^12 + (102:106)^12),  
    other = paste0(LETTERS[1:5],letters[1:5])
)
## create a csv file with 'x'
csvfile <- tempPathFile(path = getOption("fftempdir"), extension = "csv")
write.csv(
    format(x, scientific = FALSE), 
    file = csvfile, row.names = FALSE, quote = 2
)    
## read in the data without colClasses
ffx <- read.csv.ffdf(file = csvfile)
vmode(ffx)
#       id     other 
# "double" "integer"
```

Now we can coerce `ffx` to class `data.frame` with `ffx[,]` and re-format the `id` column.

```
df <- within(ffx[,], id <- format(id, scientific = FALSE))
class(df$id)
# [1] "character"
df
#                               id other
# 1 131262095302921040298042720256    Aa
# 2 131262252822013319483345600512    Bb
# 3 131262428093345052649582493696    Cc
# 4 131262622917452503293152460800    Dd
# 5 131262839257598318815163187200    Ee
```